# Is it possible to check for db updates before performing db.rollback() within a worker transaction?

Tags: python, mysql, transactions

I'm using a queue to queue transactions for a MySQL database in python. I'm using autocommit=False so that I can rollback a transaction if not all of the data queries are executed properly.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to check whether a worker has performed an action on the database before performing db.rollback()? Or can you perform db.rollback even if a worker hasn't done anything to the database without any errors occurring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, it is *not* an error to rollback a transaction where nothing else has happened, although it *is* an error to attempt to rollback when no transaction exists. To tell which is the case you can test the [`MySQLConnection.in_transaction` property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-in-transaction.html).

Comment: If the connection was initialized with `autocommit = false`, isn't there a transaction right away?

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

(which brings the connection into the same as `autocommit = false`), sending the command

```
ROLLBACK WORK;
```

(see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html )
returns with

```
0 row(s) affected
```

So, this means, you may rollback an empty transaction safely (tested on MySQL 5.1.49-3).

Alternatively, you always may store in a worker a local/static variable, which is initialized with `false`. If at least a single update command has been issued by the worker, you set this variable to `true`.

If you have to decide later on whether to `ROLLBACK` or not, you just look at the variable: if it `true`, you know that you have sent a least one update command through the DB channel.